# The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: magento-1.9, php, url-rewrite, htaccess

I installed Magento 1.9.2.0 with the sample data.
Now when I open any page of the site is returned to me an error like this:

> not Found
>   The requested URL / magento / customer / account / was not found on this server.

For all links on the homepage of the site.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Only customer module related link not working ?

Comment: please try with index.php ex.  http://example.com/index.php/customer/account/login/

Comment: Please Check your .htaccess file and magento admin panel for seo url.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. For me, it was NOT a fresh installation. It was a copy made for development. While copying, the .htaccess file was not copied. So, I copied it. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your htaccess file.

For temporary you can add `index.php` and check whether this working or not.

and after that you can do below step and your

login admin panel

go to `system->configuration->general->web->Search Engines Optimization->`

and set `Use Web Server Rewrites` to `no`

clear cache and try again

Comment: i fallowed your answer but its not working for me

Comment: go to `Base_URl/index.php/customer/account/ ` not working for you??

Comment: @ Murtuza Zabuawala thanks for your reply i found solution for it

Comment: If you found any answer then post here so other user take benifit

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari If you got the solution then post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

After reindexing

```
 php indexer.php --reindexall
```

[www.branded3.com](https://www.branded3.com/blog/re-indexing-magento-command-line/)

And flushing Magento cache (backend)
your store will be working but with /index.php/ after your domain

It seems it has to do with rewrites and SSL ([community.magento.com](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-1-x/ERROR-The-requested-URL-was-not-found-on-this-server/td-p/807/page/2))